# Использование яндекс карт в качестве инструмента для построения морских маршрутов

Tags: kotlin, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

Можно ли, на яндекс карте, для построения маршрута из точки А в Б, использовать только море, исключая сушу. А так же показывать на карте, только несколько типов объектов(порты, гавани, etc.).

Если это возможно, то прошу оставить ссылки на полезные ресурсы по этой теме, или примеры кода с подобными целями.

p.s. пишу андроид приложение на котлине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, к сожалению такой функциональности нет.